# A question about regressions and estimation

Tags: regression, nonparametric, robust

I have the following regression (all variables are vectors, i.e. its multiple-regression with $n$ responses and $m$ covariates)

$$Y = a + bX + \epsilon$$

So, $Y$ is $n$-dimensional response;
$a$ is $n$-dimensional intercept; $b$ is $n$-dimensional scale, $X$ is $n \times m$ matrix, and $\epsilon$ is $n$-dimensional error with mean zero but unknown dependence structure.

I want to estimate $a, b$ and also the right distribution for $\epsilon$.

Now, here are my questions.

1. Can the estimate of $a$ and $b$ be entirely decoupled from the estimation of $\epsilon$? For example, can I estimate $a, b$ using standard linear regression, using the so-called "normal equations", and then use that to form my residuals $Y - a - bX \approx \epsilon$ and then secondarily fit a model to this? Or, is there ways to estimate them both "at the same time"? What are the standard approaches that are commonly used?
2. One thing that confuses me is that $\epsilon$ adds to the variance of $Y$. Will this cause a problem when estimating $a, b$? For example, imagine $Y = [y_1, y_2]$, i.e. it consists of two responses, and imagine the variance of $y_1$ is twice as high as the variance of $y_2$. Will the estimation of $a, b$ using the normal equations be able to handle this? If not, what are my options? And how does this question relate to the previous question?

Comment: What is your sample size?

Answer (score 0):

Different answers will be correct in different situations. So what matters here is your prior knowledge of the situation, a.k.a. your hypothesis. The n rows might be wholly independent. Then you are solving n different linear regressions.

Alternatively, the "noise" process ϵ might be correlated among the different rows. In the opposite extreme, it might be a constant n-dimensional vector, multiplied by an normally distributed scalar. In that case, the different rows provide some mutual information.

"Noise" is a synonym for "unmodelled": your model moves all the non-linearity and much of the interaction between Y values into the ϵ term. This might be just the right move - but there is no general answer, it depends on both the data and the goals you have in mind.